# Ionic: Autocomplete div hidden behind keyboard (ng-tags-input)

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, ionic-framework, tags, ng-tags-input

How to focus on `tags-input` including `autocomplete` when keyboard is open. There is no problem with input's visibility however, the `autocomplete div` is hidden behind keyboard.

Example Plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3pLCb?p=preview)

Comment: Are u got solution for your problem?

Comment: There was no solution I was able to find. This is what I did: a `div`  manually displays all the tags. Once the user clicks on the div, a modal would open with `ng-tags-input` and a save button.